# c++ modify this output

Tags: c++

```
void print(int *xp, int len) {

 while (len--)
    cout << *xp++ << " ";  

cout << endl;
 }

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

int array[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

for(int i=10; i>0 ; i--)
    print(array, i);

return 0;
}
```

It outputs

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

   1 2 3 4 5 6 7

   1 2 3 4 5 6

   1 2 3 4 5

   1 2 3 4

   1 2 3

   1 2

   1
```

modify print() alone to generate the following output:

```
1 3 5 7 9

1 3 5 7 9

1 3 5 7

1 3 5 7

1 3 5

1 3 5

1 3

1 3

1

1
```

I tried this but it prints out all 1's

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void print(int *xp, int len) {

     while (len-- && *xp%2 != 0)

        cout << *xp << " ";

    cout << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int array[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    for(int i=10; i>0 ; i--)
        print(array, i);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Step through with a debugger.

Comment: Please give a more informative title in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Once the condition inside the `while` is false it will stop printing. So in your modified code when `*xp` is an even number it stops the whole loop.

What you want to do is either not execute the `std::cout` statement on even numbers (note that the pointer will not move either) OR jump by 2 each time. Note there are some subtleties with both approaches, and achieving the goal playing with the pointers like the original code does will be non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing the value of `xp` and so it is always printing the first element of the array.

You want to count up indices from `i`:0 -> `len` and print `*(xp+i)`

```
void print(int *xp, int len) {

 for(int i = 0; i<len;i++){
   if (i%2 == 0)
    cout << *(xp+i) << " ";  
 }

cout << endl;
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand this. when I write in *(xp+i) it gives me the array backwards it does not give me the odd ones.

Comment: @user2877258 please take a look at the code I have posted. You also appear to have changed your code in the question since I last looked at it